# Parsing commandline output progression containing carriage returns in real time with python

Tags: python, parsing, real-time, carriage-return

I am able to transform carriage returns into new lines. The problem however is to get it running in nearly 'real time'. It will be quite stupid looking if progres bar only values are 0 and 100 :-)

This code returns output at once:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['mplayer', '/home/user/sample.mkv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
for line in p.splitlines():
    if line.strip():
        print line
```

Answer (score 2):

[pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) anywhere but Windows, and [wexpect](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/) on Windows, are always my recommendations when you need to "defeat buffering" and read a subprocess's output "in near real-time", as you put it. Since the subprocess you're running most likely buffers its output differently when it's outputting to a terminal vs. anything else (as that's the normal behavior of the C runtime libraries), you need to trick it into believing it IS outputting to a terminal rather than to your program, and that's what `pexpect` achieves (by building a pseudo-terminal via the lower-level `pty` module). I'm actually amazed that `wexpect` was able to do much the same on Windows, yet, while occasionally imperfect, it does also appear to work;-).

Comment: Alex is exactly correct: to signal MPlayer not to buffer, you need to use a mechanism that's backed by a pty.

Answer (score 1):

You are in for a world of pain with buffering in my experience.  The reason being is that the standard C library will detect stdout isn't connected to a terminal and use more buffering.  There is nothing you can do about that except hack the source of `mplayer`.

If you use [python-pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) though, it will start your subprocess using pseudo-ttys which the C library believes to be a terminal and it won't reset the buffering.

It is very easy to make subprocess deadlock when doing this sort of thing too which is another problem python-pexpect gets over.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thanks! I will keep on eye for pexpect. 
But I found out that there is cosplatform way to do it: PyQt4 and QProcess. While it is not certainly solution for every program, it certainly fits for Qt4 frontend application :)

Comment: Nice.. I was just wondering how to do that in a PyQt4 application too.. The QProcess solution seems to work fine for that. If anyone interested, I'll publish the Qt4 version of this: http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Capturing_Output_from_a_Process

Answer (score -1):

You need to do two things:

1. You must make sure that `mplayer` flushes the output for every line (should happen with progress output that gets printed into the same line).
2. You must read the output line by line. Instead of calling `communicate()`, you must close the `p.stdin` and then read `p.stdout` until EOF.